# MySQL stored procedure syntax troubles

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm working on this procedure but I'm not too familiar with writing a stored procedure in MySQL, when I try to create the stored procedure as shown here, it keeps telling me that a syntax is incorrect at line 9

```
DELIMITER//

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUser (
IN new_USER_ID              BIGINT,
IN new_USER_NAME            VARCHAR(36),
IN new_ENCRYTED_PASSWORD    VARCHAR(128),
IN new_ENABLED              BIT,
IN select_Role_ID           BIGINT)
BEGIN
DECLARE user_role_id BIGINT
SET user_role_id = (SELECT max(id) from USER_ROLE);

Insert into App_User(USER_ID, USER_NAME, ENCRYTED_PASSWORD, ENABLED) 
        values(new_USER_ID, new_USER_NAME, new_ENCRYTED_PASSWORD, new_ENABLED);

INSERT INTO USER_ROLE(ID, USER_ID, ROLE_ID) 
        values(user_role_id+1, new_USER_ID, select_Role_ID);
END;//
DELIMITER;
```

Can someone show me how the correct syntax should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct way of using `delimiter`. See [mysql documentation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-delimiter/)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUser (
IN new_USER_ID              BIGINT,
IN new_USER_NAME            VARCHAR(36),
IN new_ENCRYTED_PASSWORD    VARCHAR(128),
IN new_ENABLED              BIT,
IN select_Role_ID           BIGINT)
BEGIN
   Insert into App_User(USER_ID, USER_NAME, ENCRYTED_PASSWORD, ENABLED) 
        values(new_USER_ID, new_USER_NAME, new_ENCRYTED_PASSWORD, new_ENABLED);

  INSERT INTO USER_ROLE(ID, USER_ID, ROLE_ID) 
          values(user_role_id+1, new_USER_ID, select_Role_ID);
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The DELIMITER missing in the code is cause I messed up when uploading the code to stack so you can see it in the line above the codes.

Comment: @N.Huy, there should be a space between your semicolon and delimiter `DELIMITER ;` and `DELIMITER //`